# IF: Opacity is 50% or Less Draw Circle

Tags: javascript, if-statement, draw, opacity, geometry

For one of my classes, we need to create an

```
if (...){
then draw something!
}
```

statement. However, I am super new to JavaScrip and whenever I try to create the if statement, I don't have much success.

What I am trying to do is only have a circle (by using the canvas) show if the opacity is 50% (I may change this value at a later time) or less. I have it so that the colour and opacity is randomised. I do have other shapes with this design, however, just for the purpose of this I have excluded them from the below example and JSFiddle.

Here's what I have so far: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/DonaldLouch/dt14npdp/)

```
var draw_optional = true;

if (ran_colours < "(0.5)"){
  draw_optional = true;
  context.stroke();
}
```

I was wondering am I doing something wrong? If you click on the JSFiddle link you can see my full code!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you put a breakpoint or alert statement in there to see what ran_colours looks like when you are doing your comparison?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ran_colours` looks like this: `"rgba(29,251,218,0.5617056562158282)"`.

what do you think, is `"rgba(29,251,218,0.5617056562158282)"` smaller than `"(0.5)"`? Right, you can't tell (I hope). You need to get the alpha value string, or precalculate the alpha-value and store it in its own variable. Second approach is much nicer, so here is how it's done:

Before you assign the rgba-color to `ran_colours`, add this line:

```
var alpha = Math.random();
```

In the `ran_colours` assignment, replace the last random-call with the alpha-variable

```
var ran_colours =
"rgba(" 
+ Math.floor(Math.random() * 256) + "," 
+ Math.floor(Math.random() * 256) + "," 
+ Math.floor(Math.random() * 256) + "," 
+ alpha + ")";
```

Since alpha is just a number, you can easily write your if-statement:

```
if (alpha < 0.5){
  draw_optional = true;
  context.stroke();
}
```

Comment: It worked!!! I set an alpha random value and then added the alpha condition and I also had to move all the circle code to be in the "if" statement! But thank you so much!!!